# kubelet Failed to pull image "jenkins/jenkins:lts": rpc error: code http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, kubernetes-helm

Pod is not getting created, getting the following Error message

***Warning  Failed   52m (x135 over 12h)     kubelet  Failed to pull image "jenkins/jenkins:lts": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)***

I ran a docker command from the linux command prompt  ***# docker pull jenkins/jenkins:lts***                                                                                     its downloading.

My pod status

```
        NAME                       READY   STATUS         RESTARTS   AGE
   
        jenkins-6c7786c7b6-ljvq5   0/1     ErrImagePull   0          12h
```

what is the issue how to resolve this? please advice

Comment: What does your Kubernetes manifest file look like?

Comment: you mean deployment.yaml ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image you are referring to exists:

https://hub.docker.com/layers/jenkins/jenkins/lts/images/sha256-2a15645303916751e9fd781fd403051199d94052d5d18be6e1b2398aab1f79c1?context=explore

So you should:

- check connection between cluster and docker registry (use `curl/telnet/ping`)
- specify the whole image with registry URL in the manifest you are using:

```yaml
image: registry.hub.docker.com/jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

Comment: I have modified the image paths as you mentioned but Still the issue persists

Comment: Have you checked the network connection? Why are you getting a timeout?

If you can it would be good to ssh into node and try to manually pull the image there, or start a side pod with docker -> enter its shell and run `docker pull`